# I want to get recipient_signing_uri from the Docusign API response but it returns null

Tags: laravel-8, docusignapi, docusign-sdk

**Here is the code**

```
public function send(Request $request): object
    {
       
        $apiClient = new ApiClient();
        $apiClient->getOAuth()->setOAuthBasePath(env('DS_AUTH_SERVER'));
        try {
            $accessToken = $this->getToken($apiClient);
        } catch (\Throwable $th) {
            return back()->withError($th->getMessage())->withInput();
        }
       
        $userInfo = $apiClient->getUserInfo($accessToken);
        $accountInfo = $userInfo[0]->getAccounts();
        $apiClient->getConfig()->setHost($accountInfo[0]->getBaseUri() . env('DS_ESIGN_URI_SUFFIX'));
        
        $envelopeDefenition = $this->buildEnvelope($request);
        try {
            $envelopeApi = new EnvelopesApi($apiClient);
            $result = $envelopeApi->createEnvelope($accountInfo[0]->getAccountId(), $envelopeDefenition);
            dd($result);
        } catch (\Throwable $th) {
            return back()->withError($th->getMessage())->withInput();
        }
        return view('backend.response')->with('result', $result);
    }
```

**When I print $result variable it returns a response like this**

```
container: array:8 [
    "bulk_envelope_status" => null
    "envelope_id" => "b634f8c5-96c5-4a18-947f-59418d8c4e03"
    "error_details" => null
    "recipient_signing_uri" => null
    "recipient_signing_uri_error" => null
    "status" => "sent"
    "status_date_time" => "2023-02-16T07:24:39.1570000Z"
    "uri" => "/envelopes/b634f8`your text`c5-96c5-4a18-947f-59418d8c4e03"
  ]
```

**I want to get the value of recipient signing uri in response but in my case it returns null**

How I can achieve this? Will anyone suggests?

Comment: What do you want `recipient signing uri` to represent or link to?

Comment: @LarryK My requirement is to get the value of recipient signing uri and store it in database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are not using embedded signing, you can not get the signing URL. Users will receive automated emails which they will use to sign the documents.

Answer (score 1):

createEnvelope creates the envelope. It does not give you an URL for an embedded recipient view (signing ceremony). In order to get that URL, you need to make an additional call to

[EnvelopeViews:createRecipient/](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopeviews/createrecipient/)

See this [page](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/request-signature-in-app-embedded/) for more info.

#### Also

```
$apiClient->getConfig()->setHost($accountInfo[0]->getBaseUri() . env('DS_ESIGN_URI_SUFFIX'));
```

You are using the first entry in the UserInfo returned data's **accountInfo** array. That's not a good idea. Instead, look for the entry that is the user's default account.

Or if your application is designed to work with a specific eSign account, then make sure the user has access to that account.

It is very common for DocuSign customers to have access to more than one account.

Comment: But I am not using embedded signing. Here I am using remote signing.